# Titanium email reset

Tags: email, titanium

i am trying to send a reset password email to users but so far, it has not been successful. I tried the code below but it gives me error like "no user found matching that email" but i have a user that is registered with that particular email.

```
Cloud.Users.requestResetPassword({
            email : 'email.value'
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('Success: Reset Request Sent');
    } else {
      alert('Password reset fail :' + e.message);
 }
 });
});
```

And when i try this other code, i get success alert but no email sent to the email address. SMTP settings and email templates are all good.

```
Cloud.Emails.send({
    template: 'Password',
    recipients: 'emailAddress.value'
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('Success');
    } else {
        alert('Error');
    }

});
```

Comment: alert your email.value . It must be string ,if not then set  email : ''+email.value

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I have but still not properly working. It only sends out email when i manually insert the particular email address in my code. But i want to make it for all users of my app...

Comment: i suggest you provide additional code explaining where your email.value is derived from. Then confirm there is actually a user account associated with that email address by opening up the ACS console to confirm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with email.value instead of 'email.value'

Comment: thanks stomasso. I tried email.value in the first code but it gave this error ...email is missing but when i manually insert the particular email instead of 'email.value', it works. I need help

Answer (score 0):

You should input E-mail ids instead of 'email.value', since you're passing a string there which is not a valid email id.

```
Cloud.Users.requestResetPassword({
    email: email.value
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('Success: Reset Request Sent');
    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

**Make sure that `email.value` is a valid email.** Also you should validate the email using any email validator regex before sending the request.

Read [API documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Cloud.Users-method-requestResetPassword) and [Request Reset Password](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/Users-method-request_reset_password).

Comment: hello Anand, hv gone thru the two links before coming on here, but still, i cnt solve this. Is there any other code snippet for sending emails?

Comment: have you used a valid email there?

Comment: yea i did but still nothing...plus just so you know, i have a bug issue which i have already reported to titanium developers, i do not know if its the cause of the mishap..just saying tho.